# How to upload Files into google drive using its API in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, google-drive-api, postman

I donot want users to authorize their accounts , i want them to upload data to my drive .

I tried testing the api using postman but it always fails. 
Can please someone help me debug this and how to get this in Angular , i am first trying a simple upload but this dosent work out.

Postman screenshot
[image]

Comment: Could provide more info about not wanting users to authenticate? Is the `key` param in your request a token of some sort? I’m sure that API requires authentication.

Comment: i will use my key to add the files to the drive is that possible i want to be able to use the drive as a rest api to add files and delete them

Comment: This is not a Postman question, the request fails due to Authentication (401 Unauthorised) so it’s pointing to it being an issue with your auth method. Have a look through the API docs to ensure you’re passing in the correct values in the request.